Dell Precisision 5810T
I have a Dell Precisino 5810T that came loaded with Windows 7 Pro. I had upgrade installed to Windows 10 pro. At the time everything was working for a couple of months, then the computer started to give me problems. I replaced hard drives for more memory and no wifi and Bluetooth is lost.
I went to dell.com where I'm registered and been getting info from support. They asked me about my Windows. I told them I replaced the HDD. I also asked them what operating system came in it from the factory. They said your company Ubuntu.
Please anyone, I am trying to do a reinstall fresh sp1 that came from the factory. I really like my tower with its sound device in the software. I use it for my DJ business because of turbo and its cooling fans. I need help fresh reinstalling on a new drive.

also my wi-fi stopped working at same time!

Are you trying to reinstall Windows or Ubuntu?
